# Django passing a queryset to template from views.py

Tags: django, django-views

I think i'm missing something very simple here, but I've not been able to turn up the solution yet. 
I'd like to produce a page which lists all objects matching a specific queryset. I've attempted the following, taking a value from the url to produce the appropriate query in the views.py. This query produces the expected output in the shell, but it doesn't seem to be being passed correctly to the template.

In urls.py

```
url(r'browse/(?P<sourcevolume>\w+)/$', inscription.views.browse_by_volume'),
```

In views.py

```
def browse_by_volume(request, sourcevolume):
    inscriptions_in_volume = TranslationSource.objects.filter(source=sourcevolume)
    return render_to_response('inscription/volume_browse.html', {'inscriptions_in_volume': inscriptions_in_volume})
```

Is there a mistake here, or method of doing this that i've completely missed? 
Thanks.

Comment: This looks ok, what is your template?

Comment: I've tried 
    {% for item in inscriptions_in_volume %}
        {{ item.source }}
    {% endfor %}

Comment: That seems to be correct

Comment: Is that part of the template in some outer loop or condition statement? Can you post the whole template somewhere like pastebin or dpaste?

Comment: Thanks for the responses and confirming that it is correct - it led me to look elsewhere, and realising that i'd left a entry in urls.py ( url(r'browse/', 'inscription.views.browse') ) using the same template as the browse_by_volume, above the url entry I was attempting to use, and this was fouling everything up.